# Reduce by key in an array of arrays in Scala

Tags: scala

I've created an array in Scala

```
val L = Array((1,Array(one, two, one)), (2,Array(one, three, three)))
```

And I want to get this result:

```
  Array((1,(one,2), (two,1)), (2,(one,1),(three,2)))
```

I did

```
val LL = L.map({case (s, contents) => (s, contents.map(s=>(s,1)))})
```

and got

```
LL = Array((1,Array((one,1), (two,1), (one,1))), (2,Array((one,1), (three,1), (three,1))))
```

and I want to do a reduceByKey to have that result but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
L.map { case (key, values) => 
  (key, values.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toArray) 
}
```

Comment: It is the function that returns its argument (`e => e`). So used in `groupBy` it simply groups by the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use foldLeft to iterate on each second value of the array item and count the occurrence of strings in each Array.

#### Scala repl

```
scala> val arr: Array[(Int, Array[String])] = Array((1, Array("one", "one", "two")))
arr: Array[(Int, Array[String])] = Array((1,Array(one, one, two)))

scala> arr.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])((r, c) => r.get(c).map(x => r.updated(c, x + 1)).getOrElse(r.updated(c, 1))).toArray) }
res16: Array[(Int, Array[(String, Int)])] = Array((1,Array((one,2), (two,1))))
```